# Do I need to pass empty parameters to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, optional-parameters

Say I have a function like this, which i'm calling throughout a script:

```
  function form_senden( form_name, cnf, confirm_txt, trigger_field, ,do_check, chknfcs, allow, errorMsg ){
  // do something 
  }
```

On most of my function calls, I'm only passing the first parameter.

**Question:**
Is it ok in this case to omit passing empty parameters like so:

```
  form_senden("abc");
```

Or do I need to pass all parameters regardless if they are used like so:

```
  form_senden("abc","","","","","","","","");
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend using an options object for the parameters if you have that many: `form_senden({ form_name: '...', cnf: '...')` or `form_senden(form_name, { confirm_txt: '...', allow: true })`.

Comment: and then I only pass the options that I want?

Comment: Right, a large number of positional parameters is a (bad) code smell, especially when most of them are optional. You'll be glad you did this six months down the road when you have to figure out this code again.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

form_senden("abc"); is ok

the other parameters will be initialized as undefined

Answer (score 124):

It is okay to only pass the first parameter as all other will not be set.
If you want to set the 1st and 3rd argument, you will need to make the 2nd `undefined`, like so:

```
form_senden("a",undefined,"b");
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, and is more complete than the selected answer. +1

Comment: Is there a way I can be more explicit with passing optional arguments? In python you can do something like this form_senden("a", cnf=None, "b"). Can you do something similar to this in JavaScript?

Comment: Not natively - but you can wrap your parameters into an object and hand that to the function.

Comment: undefined, not null, is the only possibility according to tslint

Answer (score 3):

you may do just `form_senden("abc");` putting default values in the function definition.

```
    function form_senden( form_name, cnf , confirm_txt , trigger_field , ,do_check , chknfcs, allow, errorMsg  ){

if(typeof(cnf)==='undefined') cnf = '';
if(typeof(confirm_txt)==='undefined') confirm_txt = ''; ...and so on
// do something 
}
```

Comment: Simple form for defining default value:  
**cnf = cnf || 'default value';**

Answer (score 2):

Omitting function parameters is okay, the missing parameters will have `undefined` value in the function.

Answer (score 2):

if you have something like:

`const myFunc = (a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) => a + b + c;`

if you call `myFunc();` you will get **6**.

but if you for example wants to call myFunc with **c = 4** and let **a** and **b** at its default values, you can call **myFunc** like this:

`myFunc(undefined, undefined, 4);` and this will return **7**.

Comment: Does JS allow myFunc( , , 4);    Or  myFunc( 3, , 4);  ??

Answer (score 1):

for completeness, in ES6 (ES2015) and later, default values can be specified

```
// `b` will default to 1

function multiply(a, b = 1) {
  return a * b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding default parameter settings.  If you are using a default parameter setting such as function f(arg=1) {}, the setting of the default value will not work with false, nulll, or zero passed in.  You must leave the arg/parameter empty or pass in undefined.

Comment: Yes.  You must pass in the word `undefined` for the function to use its default value.  It is required if you want to pass in any variables after the variable you want to leave blank.

Comment: @wbeard52 - The final arguments (parameters) passed to a javascript function can be left completely blank, no commas either.  It's only if there is a comma after the undefined value in the argument list that it needs to be specified as "undefined".

Comment: I agree with you, hence the second sentence in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I found a solution to pass null or empty values to the function. It works in node.js

```
    function returnJSON(name,value1,value2,text){
        return object = {
            'name':name,
            'value1':value1,
            'value2':value2,
            'text':text
        }
    }
    returnJSON('Hello World',undefined,undefined,'This is Text');
```